# print elements from a list until one element is found using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

so i was doing this exercise from w3schools

> 28. Write a Python program to print all even numbers from a given numbers list in the same order and stop the printing if any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

and since i read about list comprehension i wanted to put it into practice, and i came to this

```
numbers = [ 233,12,59,213,69,923,30,10,420,237,432,
           233,98,912,5,61]

print([x for i,x in enumerate(numbers) if i in 
       [i for i,x in enumerate(numbers[:numbers.index(237)])] and x % 2 == 0])
```

it works but is this the proper way of doing it? is it very ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
end = numbers.index(237)
print([x for i,x in enumerate(numbers) if x%2==0 and i<end])
```

You could try this. Replace `end` with it's value to implement it in a single line.

Output :

```py
[12, 30, 10, 420]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate and the % operator:

```
numbers = [ 233,12,59,213,69,923,30,10,420,237,432,
           233,98,912,5,61]

print([num for idx, num in enumerate(numbers) if num % 2 == 0 and idx < numbers.index(237)])
```

Output:

```
[12, 30, 10, 420]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in numbers[:numbers.index(237)] if x%2==0]
```